# Assembly: "junk `oc' after expression"

Tags: gcc, assembly

I am trying to generate the hex representation of the following assembly code. I am doing a buffer overflow lab where I need to get commands into the stack. When I try to compile the following code with command:

```
gcc -m32 -c assemblylevel2.s
```

I get the error:

> assemblylevel2.s:2: Error: junk `oc' after expression

I've tried the code with varying permutations of mov, movl, push, pushl. It all generates the same error. How can I get this to compile?

assemblylevel2.s:

```
movl $0xfaa6ef53, 0x804d108
pushl $0x8048d0c
ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given it's complaining about `oc` on line 2, I would first check that your code isn't *actually* like this:

```
movl $0xfaa6ef53, 0x804d108
pushl $0x8048doc             ;; oh-see rather than zero-see
ret
```

That would certainly make it an invalid hex number, and therefore cause an error such as what you're seeing.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly it. I've stared at this for nearly an hour. Thank you!